# Entity Framework WPF multiuser architecture

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, multi-user

I'm hoping this is a daft question with a simple answer...

I have developed my first business app using MSSQL/EF/MVVM/WPF and now I'm trying to get it to work in a multi user environment.
I have seen lots of answers that suggest polling to see if database has changed, and then resolving concurrency issues, or suggestions that each client should have a local database installed and syncing them. Both these look like a lot of work to me.

Is it OK to have a shared repository on the server? The repository could load from the whole database when it starts (about 50000 records). Then the clients could just query the same repository. If one user changes some data, the repository fires propertychanged notifications back to all the other clients. Am I thinking about this wrong, or what is the accepted method?

Thanks

Comment: this question will probably get flagged as too broad - but yeah, sounds reasonable so far.

Comment: web server, backed by a database. Webapi frontend. HttpClients for connections, signalr on the server to notify clients of CRUDs, and [HubConnections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.hubconnection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in clients to listen for these updates.  It's going to be a lot of work, but relatively straight forward and rewarding.

Comment: Thanks Will. I will look into SignalR next time I do a web application. However this is WPF.

Comment: @TheMeanFiddler So what? WPF applications are not allowed to use a web based data hub? Want it quick, dirty and not suppoer efficient (but fast to implement) use SignalR. Need high performance like in trading - write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do WILL bea lot of work.

Having an application server keeping state and distributing it is standard design - for example for trading applications. You use the database for reporting etc. - but you keep the current state in memory and distribute it from there.

Comment: Thanks TomTom. That's very reassuring. I'm still baffled, and I don't know where to look for examples. Surely multi-user WPF apps are a standard architecture?

Comment: The way I understand it, my DAL and repository sit on the server and the client's viewmodels talk to it (over LAN) through WCF. Is this correct? There are only 5 users. I do not need highly efficient solutions - just something that is easy to implement. Thanks